flutter - how can i handle the response of the request made in webview
is there a way to handle json response of a request that made in webview on flutter? so the scenario is:

the website is making a request inside webview. so i am not sending any request manually. basically website sends a http request to /api/v1/fetch
when the response of the request the website sent is returned i need to handle json response.

I tried to use useShouldInterceptRequest but can't achieve it.
i am using flutter inapwebview package:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview

Have you read the documentation of this pacakage?
You can read this: https://inappwebview.dev/docs/webview/in-app-weview-settings/#useshouldinterceptajxrequest
An example implementation is (not tester):
InAppWebView(
                        initialUrl: Uri.https(authState.companyData.baseUrl,
                                '/administrator/Web.do')
                            .toString(),
                        initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
                            crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
                                debuggingEnabled: true,
                                useShouldInterceptAjaxRequest: true),
                            ios: IOSInAppWebViewOptions(
                                sharedCookiesEnabled: true),
                            ),
                        onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
                          webView = controller;
                        },
                        onLoadStop: (controller, url) async {
                          if (url.toLowerCase().endsWith('logout.do')) {
                            BlocProvider.of<AdminBloc>(context)
                                .add(AdminPageLogout());
                            // BlocProvider.of<AuthenticationBloc>(context)
                            //     .add(AuthenticationLoggedOut());
                            // BlocProvider.of<AuthenticationBloc>(context)
                            //     .add(AuthenticationStarted());
                          }
                          webView.canGoBack().then((value) {
                            setState(() {
                              canGoBack = value;
                            });
                          });
                          webView.canGoForward().then((value) {
                            setState(() {
                              canGoForward = value;
                            });
                          });
                        },
                        onProgressChanged: (controller, progress) {
                          setState(() {
                            loadingProgress = progress / 100;
                          });
                        },
                        shouldInterceptAjaxRequest:
                            (InAppWebViewController controller,
                                AjaxRequest ajaxRequest) async {
                          print(ajaxRequest.url);
                          ajaxRequest.headers.setRequestHeader("Cookie", authState.setCookie);
                          return ajaxRequest;
                        },
                        onAjaxReadyStateChange:
                            (InAppWebViewController controller,
                                AjaxRequest ajaxRequest) async {
                          print(ajaxRequest.status);
                          return AjaxRequestAction.PROCEED;
                        },
                        onAjaxProgress: (InAppWebViewController controller,
                            AjaxRequest ajaxRequest) async {
                          print(ajaxRequest.status);
                          return AjaxRequestAction.PROCEED;
                        },
                      )

Please refer to useShouldInterceptAjaxRequest: true to activate ajax request interceptions and to :
shouldInterceptAjaxRequest:
                            (InAppWebViewController controller,
                                AjaxRequest ajaxRequest) async {
                          print(ajaxRequest.url);
                          ajaxRequest.headers.setRequestHeader("Cookie", authState.setCookie);
                          return ajaxRequest;
                        },

To handle interception.
See also: Intercepting AJAX in Flutter webview works on iOS but not Android
